# How to place a picture on top of screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

i want to create a screen for movie details in react native.
I created a component for the movie poster which is gonna contain an image of the movie and it's details (name, release date) :

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const PosterRow = ({ infos, image }) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style = {styles.backgroundContainer}>
        <Image source = {image} resizeMode = 'cover' style = {styles.backdrop} />
      </View>
      <View style = {styles.overlay}>
        <Text style = {styles.headline}>{infos.movieName}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

And for the details screen :

```
    const detailsScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const { movieName, releaseYear } = route.params;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
      <View style={styles.poster} >
        <PosterRow  infos = {{movieName,releaseYear}} image={DEFAULT_PICTURE}/>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.info}>
        <Text style={styles.releaseYear}>{releaseYear}</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  title: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  releaseYear: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  poster : {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '50%',
  },
  info: {
    flex: 2
  },
});
```

How can i achieve the final result as in the image :

[image: movie details]

My current result :
[image: current result]

Comment: What's your current result?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior i've added my current result in the post